# How do I change UIWebView depending on screen size of iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am building an iPhone app that is just a UIWebView.  When I tried to run this app on my phone, I get a large black bar at the top and bottom of the screen.  I believe because it's because it's optimized for smaller screens.  On my iPhone 5 though, it's not optimal.

How do I change the size of the UIWebView depending on the type of iPhone (screen size)?

[image]

Here is the screenshot of my xib file.
[image]

Comment: dont center your webview. set the frame like `webview.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);`

Comment: it is not of webview problem, problem with your window itself increase from and follow add moutainLion code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things you can do:

1)  set an iPhone 5 specific default (splash) screen (the Default-568h@2x.png file listed by Chris ... +1 to him)

and

2)  use autolayout and make certain your webview has zero width between the top and bottom edges of the window / container view.

You can turn it on in your storyboard or XIB by checking this checkbox:

[image]

Comment: I've included a screenshot of my xib with autolayout checked.  I'm still facing the same problem when I view the app on my phone.

Answer (score 3):

First, add a default image named `Default-568h@2x.png` to your project. This gets rid of the black bars on the iPhone 5. Then, to change the web views size for each screen, in interface builder in the right pane, click on the ruler icon and in the bottom left of the pane, change the settings so it looks like this (this assumes autolayout is off)

[image]

If your not using IB, do what @Dilip wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Change you webview size according to divice size.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
            if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) {

    webView.frame= CGRectMake(yourX, yourY, yourWidth, yourHeight);
            } else {

    webView.frame= CGRectMake(yourX, yourY, yourWidth, yourHeight);
            }
     [super viewDidLoad];
    }
```

And you have to add one Default-568h@2x.png(640 × 1136) so iphone know that this app can run on iphone5

Comment: where do I include this piece of code?  I only have a - (void) viewDidLoad method in viewcontroller.m.  And I'm still unclear on how I change the webview size.

Comment: you have to add this code in `- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
` method.

Comment: or it is first view than you can also add it in `viewdidload` method. but `initWithNibName` is preferable way. and also dont forget to add `Default-568h@2x.png(640 × 1136)` image...

Answer (score 0):

Well for doing this you have to add a condition when you are creating your **UIWebView** ,

```
CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
if(result.height == 480)
{
    UIWebView *aWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
}
else if(result.height == 568)
{
  UIWebView *aWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
}
```

This condition checks for the screen size . Hope this helps !! :)

Answer (score 0):

To find if its iPhone5

```
#define IS_IPHONE5 (([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-568)?NO:YES)
```

define the height

```
#define iPhoneScreenHeight   (([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-568)?480:568)
```